# Sorting by property in Java 8 stream

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Oh, those tricky Java 8 streams with lambdas. They are very powerful, yet the intricacies take a bit to wrap one's header around it all.

Let's say I have a `User` type with a property `User.getName()`. Let's say I have a map of those users `Map<String, User>` associated with names (login usernames, for example). Let's further say I have an instance of a comparator `UserNameComparator.INSTANCE` to sort usernames (perhaps with fancy collators and such).

So how do I get a list of the users in the map, sorted by username? I can ignore the map keys and do this:

```
return userMap.values()
    .stream()
    .sorted((u1, u2) -> {
      return UserNameComparator.INSTANCE.compare(u1.getName(), u2.getName());
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But that line where I have to extract the name to use the `UserNameComparator.INSTANCE` seems like too much manual work. Is there any way I can simply supply `User::getName` as some mapping function, just for the sorting, and still get the `User` instances back in the collected list?

Bonus: What if the thing I wanted to sort on were two levels deep, such as `User.getProfile().getUsername()`?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

What you want is [`Comparator#comparing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-):

```
userMap.values().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(User::getName, UserNameComparator.INSTANCE))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For the second part of your question, you would just use

```
Comparator.comparing(
    u->u.getProfile().getUsername(), 
    UserNameComparator.INSTANCE
)
```

Comment: Wow, my brain almost hurts, but that was exactly what I was looking for, bonus and everything! And super-quick response, too. Thanks!

Comment: For followers, if you don't need to special comparator, you can also use `Comparator.comparing(o -> o.getUsername())` or `Comparator.comparing(UserNameComparator.INSTANCE)` if it could accept users instead of names.  FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

for comparing in the level two, you can proceed like that :
for the object

```
public class ArticleChannel {

    private Long id;
    private String label;
    private ArticleBusiness business;
}

public class ArticleBusiness {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}

articleChannelList.sort(Comparator.comparing((ArticleChannel articleChannel) -> **articleChannel.getBusiness().getName()**).thenComparing(ArticleChannel::getLabel));
```