# Sorting in Java8 Streams

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-stream

```
   AA {
      Float key;
      String val;
   }
   A is an object of class AA.
   Set <String> s1 = A.stream()
                      .filter(var->var.key > 5) 
                      .sort('What to do')
                      .map(A::value)
                      .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

How to sort the set in descending order based on the value of Key? 
I need the val's to be arranged in set in descending order based on key.

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568555/sorting-by-property-in-java-8-stream

Comment: If `A` is an object of class `AA` then it has no `stream()` method. Please [edit] your question and convert it to valid Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.sort((a1, a2) -> Float.compare(a2.key, a1.key))
```

Comment: Unrelated: I gave that user simple, direct feedback. That's all. I have seen more than once that newbies put up such stuff ... until A) they get banned or B) they receive a *clear* message that their behavior is in fact *rude*.

Answer (score 0):

Try using comparator here,

```
Collections.sort(s1, 
(o1,o2)-> ..//compare implementation
);
```

Or you can use

```
s1.stream()
     .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()
// or your own compare implementation)
```