# Java stream filter to take 1 element

Tags: java, jpa

so i have a class here

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;

    private Double k1;

    private Double k2;

    private Double k3;

    private Double k4;
}
```

and i have found all the list with Spring data jpa with findAll() method

but i want to take all the list with just all the k1 data

so i make it in the service

```
List<Employee> employeeList = findAll();

        List<Double> k1List = employeeList.stream()
                .filter(k -> k.getK1())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but it return Boolean and return Employee data type
how to findAll k1 with the lambda?

Comment: As all the answers suggest, use map. However, I would specify it as `map(Employee::getK1)` using a method reference as it adds a bit of clarity as to where the value is coming from.  But `map(employee->employee.getK1())` offers the same information.

Answer (score 0):

`filter()` funcitons is used to filter out data from your `employeeList`. It can't be used to filter out the attributes of employees. I believe what you need here is a `map()` function.

```java
List<Employee> employeeList = findAll();

        List<Double> k1List = employeeList.stream()
                .map(k -> k.getK1())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can use the `filter()` function to filter out employee records with a condition like this. For example get all employees where `k1` value is equal to `1.0`

```java
List<Employee> employeeList = findAll();

        List<Employee> filteredEmployeeList = employeeList.stream()
                .filter(k -> k.getK1() == 1.0)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note the returned type of `map()` function and `filter()` function where `map()` funciton returns extracted double value and `filter()` function returns the same type as the original list.

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to accept the answer if this solved your issue. :)

Comment: i have a class like this 

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;

    private Double k1;

    private Double k2;
}
```

and i have a list of these:

```
Employee employee1 = (String daniel, Double 2.0, Double 3.0);
Employee employee2 = (String alex, Double 5.0, Double 6.0);
Employee employee3 = (String hans, Double 3.0, Double 3.0);

List<Employee> employeeList = Arrays.asList(employee1, employee2, employee3);
```

how do i can sort the employeeList based on k1 or k2?

Comment: Please post a new question as the topic is different. And it's a bit hard to answer when the code is in a single line.

Comment: Anyway I guess this can answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568555/sorting-by-property-in-java-8-stream